# Can you determine values in a set of integers from a known sum and product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, integers

**Question:**

- There is a set of numbers defined as {A, B, C, D, E}
- The sum of the set is 49 (A+B+C+D+E = 49)
- The product of the set is 13000 (ABCDE = 13000)
- All numbers in the set are positive

1) Can you determine the values of A, B, C, D, and E?
2) Can you find all possible solutions? (Assuming switching values does not count as another solution i.e. switching A and E is not another solution)

**Notes:**

The answer is either {1, 5, 10, 13, 20} or {2, 4, 5, 13, 25} though I am looking for a process to solve it

- This will be done by a computer so complexity is not an issue though speed is
- Code answers are equally welcome

To clarify, this is a personal project, not homework help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you essentially want, is factors of $13000$ that are below the number $49$. Once you have these, then I think this is a subset-sum problem (with subset size constraint).

Comment: The factors are less than or equal to $49$ because their sum has to be $49$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the following system (since you are using a computer):
\begin{cases}
A+B+C+D+E=49\\
\ln A+\ln B+\ln C+\ln D+\ln E = \ln 13 000
\end{cases}

Comment: You sir are legendary, thank you so much